# Alternative to target="_blank" when using XHTML strict and no javascript!

Tags: xhtml, accessibility

I need to use XHTML strict

I need to ensure my site works with no javascript.

I need to open a new help window from my own application. Of course I wanted to use  target="_blank" when no javascript detected but this is not XHTML strict.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Is the target attribute not xhtml strict or the value _blank?

Comment: No, the target attribute is not allowed in XHTML Strict.

Comment: Why don't you propose help in the same window?
And a link back to the previous page?
I know it can be tedious, if you want to be able to manipulate the page, and have the help aside (but why not simply add the help ASIDE?).

Comment: @Philippe: Not without risking jail time at least!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You **have to** use javascript in this case. If you don't want to use javascript, and still have valid markup, don't use XHTML Strict as your doctype.

```
document.getElementById("mylink").target = "_blank";
```

Or you can attach a click-event to the link that opens the address up in a new window. Either way, javascript is your solution if you want valid markup.

Comment: without using javascript and still XHTML Strict?

Comment: The title was *asking*. It's not possible without javascript.

Comment: Yes its client driven and my hands are tied!

Comment: @AJM, You can either use XHTML Strict + Javascript, or a less-strict doctype without javascript.

Comment: Thought so, Im doing the javascript thing already. This is for degrading.

Comment: @AJM, Let your client know that this is the standard in the professional world. There's nothing they need to be worried about.

Answer (score 6):

You can only do this by:

- Use Transitional doctype
- or use JavaScript

Don't force new windows on visitors

Comment: I need to use XHTML strict
I need to ensure my site works with no javascript.

Comment: @AJM: and how exactly does it not "work" if you can't force a new window? What's wrong with letting the user decide which links to open in a new window?

Comment: Who are these monsters disallowing the use of Javascript!

Comment: A lot of project managers and sales people don't want the visitor to leave their page. I hear it all the time.

Answer (score 5):

This is the easy way:

```
<a href="link" onclick="target='_blank'">link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="this.target= '_blank';return true;" >Google</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there may be a way to do this without javascript. You can write a custom DTD as described [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customdtd/).

Add a target attribute to your customization and it will validate. I just came up with this idea and I'm not sure if I'm missing any drawbacks.

Answer (score -4):

Try to use this:

```
http://www.webaddress.com' target='_blank'
```

as the address.

Comment: The question is ALTERNATIVE to target='_blank'