# Anchor tags and target behaviour? - HTML

Tags: html, anchor, target

I must say that despite this being a newb question, I don't think I have totally mastered HTML a tags.

Whenever I want to open a link in a new tab I add **target="_blank"**, works fine in chrome and firefox. Not in IE7-8.

I think the behaviour might have something to do with the DOCTYPE, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm currently using **HTML 4.01 Strict**.

---

Right now what I am trying to understand is:

- How to open links in new tabs in IE7-8
- How to open links within **small windows**

[image]

---

Help would be very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

`target` attribute for links is not part of HTML 4.01 Strict. Generally speaking, opening new windows is considered [bad usability](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html). See also [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211928/alternative-to-target-blank-when-using-xhtml-strict-and-no-javascript). To control window's size, you need to use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open).

Comment: @Yaggo: opening new windows or new tabs? I can't get to open new tabs within IE, is this normal? Btw thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Tab or window, doesn't matter. Let the user control how links open and use absolute positioned divs or similar for popup functionality.